# Can Access VBA tell the difference between typing into a combo box and selecting from a drop down?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I've got a combo box, "Filter Dropdown", that triggers some VBA code on `Filter_Dropdown_Change()`.

The problem I'm having is I want it to trigger once the *final* value has been selected. So, currently, it triggers when I select a value from the dropdown, which is fine, but also when I type anything, because each character counts as a change - which I don't want.

Is there a way of telling when I've finished typing a new value into the combo box? Can Access differentiate at all between selecting a pre-existing value and typing a new one?

I suspect I'm using the wrong event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AfterUpdate` or `BeforeUpdate` event